# How to call inbuilt method of location listener in another class

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

I am using location listener to track the location.I implement the location listener, there are inbuilt methods of location listener such as onLocationChanged,OnstatusChanged,onProviderEnabled etc.Whenerver the location changed it will hit on server but I want to do at every 10 min of interval So I am using timer for that after every 10 mins it will hit the location. I cannot call the method inside the timer. So how to do it.

```
public class LocationMonitoringService  implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {


    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Context mContext;

    private final LocationRepository mLocationRepository;

    private final ShareLocationAdapterClass mAdapter;

    private final SyncOfflineRepository syncOfflineRepository;

    private long updatedTime = 0;

    private final List<UserLocationPojo> mUserLocationPojoList;

    private final SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository syncOfflineAttendanceRepository;


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    long notify_interval = 1000 * 60 * 5;


    public LocationMonitoringService(final Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        mLocationRepository = new LocationRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineRepository = new SyncOfflineRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository = new SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        mUserLocationPojoList = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new ShareLocationAdapterClass();

        mAdapter.setShareLocationListener(new ShareLocationAdapterClass.ShareLocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccessCallBack(boolean isAttendanceOff) {
                if (isAttendanceOff && !syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkIsAttendanceIn()) {
                    AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                    ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailureCallBack() {

            }
        });
    }



    public void onStartTacking() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        //Exception thrown when GPS or Network provider were not available on the user's device.
        try {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

            //API level 9 and up
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);



            int gpsFreqInDistance =100;

            assert locationManager != null;
            locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);


            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);



        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void onStopTracking(Context context) {
        mAdapter.shareLocation();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
//        cancelAlarm(context, (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));


    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */


    //to get the location change
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("okh ", "onLocationChanged:   "+System.currentTimeMillis());


        if (location != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));

            if (!AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())) && !AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()))) {

                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LAT, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LONG, String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

                if (Prefs.getBoolean(AUtils.PREFS.IS_ON_DUTY, false)) {
                    if (updatedTime == 0) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);
                    }

                    if ((updatedTime + AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL_MINUTES) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);

                    }

                    mTimer = new Timer();
                    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5,notify_interval);
//                   sendLocation();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:  no location found !!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged" + provider + "Status" + status);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderEnabled" + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderDisabled" + provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

    }



   private void sendLocation() {

        //  mAdapter.shareLocation(getTempList());
        Log.d("okh", "sendLocation: Current Time In Millies "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

        try {
            Calendar CurrentTime = AUtils.getCurrentTime();
            Calendar DutyOffTime = AUtils.getDutyEndTime();

            if (CurrentTime.before(DutyOffTime)) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Before");

                UserLocationPojo userLocationPojo = new UserLocationPojo();

                userLocationPojo.setUserId(Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_ID, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLat(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLong(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, ""));
                double startLat = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, "0"));
                double startLng = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, "0"));
                userLocationPojo.setDistance(String.valueOf(AUtils.calculateDistance(
                        AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext(), startLat, startLng)));
//                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTime()); //TODO
                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTimeLocal());
                userLocationPojo.setOfflineId("0");

                userLocationPojo.setIsOffline(AUtils.isInternetAvailable() && AUtils.isConnectedFast(mContext));

                String UserTypeId = Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_TYPE_ID, AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI);
                if (AUtils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                    TableDataCountPojo.LocationCollectionCount count = syncOfflineRepository.getLocationCollectionCount(AUtils.getLocalDate());
                    if ((UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI) || UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_WASTE_MANAGER))
                            && (count.getLocationCount() > 0 || count.getCollectionCount() > 0)) {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    } else {
                        mUserLocationPojoList.add(userLocationPojo);
                        mAdapter.shareLocation(mUserLocationPojoList);
                        mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_EMP_SCANNIFY)) {
                        Type type = new TypeToken<UserLocationPojo>() {
                        }.getType();
                        mLocationRepository.insertUserLocationEntity(new Gson().toJson(userLocationPojo, type));
                    } else {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    }
                    mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "After");

                syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.performCollectionInsert(mContext,
                        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkAttendance(), AUtils.getCurrentDateDutyOffTime());

                AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();

                Activity activity = ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant);

                if (activity instanceof DashboardActivity) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                    AUtils.DutyOffFromService = true;
                }

                if (!AUtils.isNull(AUtils.currentContextConstant)) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
  


    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendLocation();


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: did the run method has the reference to call onLocationChanged()

Comment: @DeePanShu-no,how to do it

Comment: from where onLocationChanged() calling from first time, pls. share that code

Comment: It is the inbuilt method of location listener,I have updated the code pls see it

Comment: you can make LocationManager as class field which is accessible from everywhere and then request update from timertask. no need to make LocationManager instance in different methods to start and stop.

Comment: Will you pls show me how to do it, bcz i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code please try this:

```
public class LocationMonitoringService  implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {


    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Context mContext;

    private final LocationRepository mLocationRepository;

    private final ShareLocationAdapterClass mAdapter;

    private final SyncOfflineRepository syncOfflineRepository;

    private long updatedTime = 0;

    private int gpsFreqInDistance =100;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private final List<UserLocationPojo> mUserLocationPojoList;

    private final SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository syncOfflineAttendanceRepository;


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    long notify_interval = 1000 * 60 * 5;


    public LocationMonitoringService(final Context context) {
        mContext = context;
      
        // here we declare the variable as a field for this class instance
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mLocationRepository = new LocationRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineRepository = new SyncOfflineRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository = new SyncOfflineAttendanceRepository(AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext());

        mUserLocationPojoList = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new ShareLocationAdapterClass();

        mAdapter.setShareLocationListener(new ShareLocationAdapterClass.ShareLocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccessCallBack(boolean isAttendanceOff) {
                if (isAttendanceOff && !syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkIsAttendanceIn()) {
                    AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                    ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailureCallBack() {

            }
        });
    }



    public void onStartTacking() {


        //Exception thrown when GPS or Network provider were not available on the user's device.
        try {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

            //API level 9 and up
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);




            assert locationManager != null;
            locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);


            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);



        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTacking: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void onStopTracking(Context context) {
        mAdapter.shareLocation();

       // removed initialization from here

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
//        cancelAlarm(context, (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));


    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */


    //to get the location change
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("okh ", "onLocationChanged:   "+System.currentTimeMillis());


        if (location != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));

            if (!AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())) && !AUtils.isNullString(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()))) {

                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LAT, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                Prefs.putString(AUtils.LONG, String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

                if (Prefs.getBoolean(AUtils.PREFS.IS_ON_DUTY, false)) {
                    if (updatedTime == 0) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);
                    }

                    if ((updatedTime + AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL_MINUTES) <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        updatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Log.d(TAG, "updated Time ==== " + updatedTime);

                    }

                    mTimer = new Timer();
                    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5,notify_interval);
//                   sendLocation();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged:  no location found !!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged" + provider + "Status" + status);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderEnabled" + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d(TAG, " onProviderDisabled" + provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

    }



   private void sendLocation() {

        //  mAdapter.shareLocation(getTempList());
        Log.d("okh", "sendLocation: Current Time In Millies "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

        try {
            Calendar CurrentTime = AUtils.getCurrentTime();
            Calendar DutyOffTime = AUtils.getDutyEndTime();

            if (CurrentTime.before(DutyOffTime)) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Before");

                UserLocationPojo userLocationPojo = new UserLocationPojo();

                userLocationPojo.setUserId(Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_ID, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLat(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, ""));
                userLocationPojo.setLong(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, ""));
                double startLat = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LAT, "0"));
                double startLng = Double.parseDouble(Prefs.getString(AUtils.LONG, "0"));
                userLocationPojo.setDistance(String.valueOf(AUtils.calculateDistance(
                        AUtils.mainApplicationConstant.getApplicationContext(), startLat, startLng)));
//                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTime()); //TODO
                userLocationPojo.setDatetime(AUtils.getServerDateTimeLocal());
                userLocationPojo.setOfflineId("0");

                userLocationPojo.setIsOffline(AUtils.isInternetAvailable() && AUtils.isConnectedFast(mContext));

                String UserTypeId = Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.USER_TYPE_ID, AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI);
                if (AUtils.isInternetAvailable()) {
                    TableDataCountPojo.LocationCollectionCount count = syncOfflineRepository.getLocationCollectionCount(AUtils.getLocalDate());
                    if ((UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_GHANTA_GADI) || UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_WASTE_MANAGER))
                            && (count.getLocationCount() > 0 || count.getCollectionCount() > 0)) {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    } else {
                        mUserLocationPojoList.add(userLocationPojo);
                        mAdapter.shareLocation(mUserLocationPojoList);
                        mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (UserTypeId.equals(AUtils.USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE_EMP_SCANNIFY)) {
                        Type type = new TypeToken<UserLocationPojo>() {
                        }.getType();
                        mLocationRepository.insertUserLocationEntity(new Gson().toJson(userLocationPojo, type));
                    } else {
                        syncOfflineRepository.insetUserLocation(userLocationPojo);
                    }
                    mUserLocationPojoList.clear();
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "After");

                syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.performCollectionInsert(mContext,
                        syncOfflineAttendanceRepository.checkAttendance(), AUtils.getCurrentDateDutyOffTime());

                AUtils.setIsOnduty(false);
                ((MyApplication) AUtils.mainApplicationConstant).stopLocationTracking();

                Activity activity = ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant);

                if (activity instanceof DashboardActivity) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                    AUtils.DutyOffFromService = true;
                }

                if (!AUtils.isNull(AUtils.currentContextConstant)) {
                    ((Activity) AUtils.currentContextConstant).recreate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
  


    private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, AUtils.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    gpsFreqInDistance, this,null);


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: cant cast  gpsFreqInDistance in TimerTaskToGetLocation even if i create private field of it

Comment: I edited the answer, take as class field same as we take from LocationManager